# "ProtocolError: Runtime.callFunctionOn timed out" while creating PDF for Docusaurus site using Puppeteer docs-to-pdf

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, pdf-generation, settimeout, docusaurus

I am trying to generate a PDF from a Docusaurus site using the [docs-to-pdf tool](https://github.com/jean-humann/docs-to-pdf). I successfully did that for a smaller site but I get this error on a medium-sized website. **I can't find a way to increase the timeout or a way to resolve this error.** I searched but found people had the same error even after increasing the timeout.
P.S. I am not TS/JS savvy.

```
[14.11.2023 12:47.56.629] [LOG]   Success
[14.11.2023 12:47.56.630] [LOG]   Start generating PDF...
[14.11.2023 12:47.56.631] [LOG]   Generate cover...
[14.11.2023 12:47.56.631] [LOG]   Start generating TOC...
[14.11.2023 12:47.56.646] [LOG]   Restructuring the html of a document...
[14.11.2023 12:47.57.939] [LOG]   Scroll to the bottom of the page...
[14.11.2023 12:50.57.954] [ERROR] ProtocolError: Runtime.callFunctionOn timed out. Increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect calls for a higher timeout if needed.
    at <instance_members_initializer> (C:\Users\Nida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docs-to-pdf\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\CallbackRegistry.js:96:14)
    at new Callback (C:\Users\Nida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docs-to-pdf\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\CallbackRegistry.js:100:16)
    at CallbackRegistry.create (C:\Users\Nida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docs-to-pdf\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\CallbackRegistry.js:32:26)
    at Connection._rawSend (C:\Users\Nida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docs-to-pdf\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\Connection.js:91:26)
    at CdpCDPSession.send (C:\Users\Nida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docs-to-pdf\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\CDPSession.js:78:33)
    at #evaluate (C:\Users\Nida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docs-to-pdf\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\ExecutionContext.js:211:50)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\Nida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docs-to-pdf\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\ExecutionContext.js:126:16)
    at async IsolatedWorld.evaluate (C:\Users\Nida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docs-to-pdf\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\IsolatedWorld.js:128:16)
    at async CdpPage.evaluate (C:\Users\Nida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docs-to-pdf\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\Page.js:900:20)
```

I tried the same command I had successfully generated a PDF for but used a medium-sized website instead which resulted in the error. This command:

```
npx docs-to-pdf docusaurus --initialDocURLs="https://docs.apimatic.io" --contentSelector="article" --paginationSelector="a.pagination-nav__link.pagination-nav__link--next"
```

**I haven't changed anything in my docusaurus code** except installing this tool using the command

```
npm install -g docs-to-pdf
```